# is there any way to add version build number for all including css files

Tags: php, css, yii

I have a lot of places of including CSS files something like this

```
$cs->registerScriptFile($cs->getCoreScriptUrl() . '/js/jquery/jquery.cookie.js');
```

and I have a constant version-build, which is incrementing after each commit. Is there any way to add

```
?v=VERSION-BUILD
```

param for all script registrations, do not hardcoding it, or rewriting yii lib?

Comment: Not too familair with that framework but doing a quick search I see Yii has an [asset manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/#hh3) which seems to handle this... maybe with additional features if using Gii?

Answer (score 4):

Personally, for my own purposes, I've extended CClientScript class to make it add unique parameter to each script and css. It can easily be improved to fit your needs.

I've prepared an untested simple version of this Component. The idea is to override CClientScript's render() method, which is called before any script files are echoed:

```
class ClientScript extends CCLientScript
{

public $version=1;

public function render(&$output)
{
    if(!$this->hasScripts)
        return;
    if ($this->version!==false)
    {
        foreach ($this->scriptFiles as $position=>&$scripts)
        {
            foreach ($scripts as &$script)
            {
                $script.="?".$this->version;
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->cssFiles as $position=>&$styles)
        {
            foreach ($styles as &$style)
            {
                $style.="?".$this->version;
            }
        }
    }
    parent::render($output);
}
}
```

Put this class, say, in "components" folder. Now you can use it instead of CClientScript by configuring your app's parameters, usually in config/main.php:

```
'clientScript' => array(
    'class' => 'ClientScript',
    'version'=>2,
    //the rest parameters are same as usual. you can set up packages here and so on.
)
```

The code can be improved to skip versioning of such files as jquery and other third-party libraries - it's up to you.

Comment: if it possible to add subdomain in such way, i want to remove all static files to CDN, so i need to add cdn. in absolute url, but $this->scriptFiles contain only relative URL's

Comment: ok! I've done it :) 
    public function setCoreScriptUrl($value)
    {
        $baseUrl = str_replace('://','://cdn.',\Yii::app()->baseUrl);
        $value=$baseUrl.$value;
        parent::setCoreScriptUrl($value);
    }